# How can I idenitfy selected points uniquely using plotly event data?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

The coordinates from `event_data` are rounded, so how can I be guaranteed to identify the selected data? For example, if the two center points are selected, `event_data` returns the same x value:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ui = fluidPage(
  # Plot
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  # Table for x y coordinates
  tableOutput("text")
)

# Create plot
dataDf = data.frame(x = c(-10, 1.004, 1.005, 10), 
                    y = c(-10, 0, 0, 10))
plt = ggplot(dataDf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
ply = ggplotly(plt, source = "plot")

server = function(input, output) {
  
  # Display plot
  output$plot = renderPlotly(ply)
  
  # Show x and y values of selected points in a table
  output$text = renderTable({
    eventData = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "plot")
    data.frame(x = eventData$x, y = eventData$y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the desired number of digits in `renderTable`:

```r
  output$text = renderTable({
    eventData = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "plot")
    print(eventData)
    data.frame(x = eventData$x, y = eventData$y)
  }, digits = 6)
```

Comment: This solves the example I provided. The "problem" appears to be only in the displaying `event_data` values in certain contexts. For example, the underlying value can be seen if copied to a variable: `x = eventData$x[1]; print(x)`